# Why string with encoding 'UTF-8' have broken symbols when I looping the string

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have string with umlauts in utf-8 and it displayed ok:

```
var_dump($content);
```

It return me "höst lanseras".
But when I try this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($content) - 1; $i++) {
    var_dump($content[$i]);
}
```

I have this:

```
string(1) "h"
string(1) "o"
string(1) "�"
string(1) "�"
string(1) "s"
string(1) "t"
string(1) " "
string(1) "l"
string(1) "a"
string(1) "n"
string(1) "s"
string(1) "e"
string(1) "r"
string(1) "a"
string(1) "s"
```

How to get umlaut symbol as element of array?

Comment: UTF-8 is using more bytes for a string. Test `mb_strlen($content)==strlen($content)`.

Comment: PHP treats strings as list of bytes, not characters. See [What every programmer absolutely, positively needs to know about encodings and character sets to work with text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: Notice 13 chars in your `var_dump($content);` output and 15 chars in your looped `var_dump($content[$i]);` output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within UTF-8, "ö" is encoded using more than one byte.
PHP strings are dumb byte arrays; PHP is not aware of "characters" or such at all.
Accessing string offsets using `$str[x]` accesses one specific byte; `strlen` reports the length in bytes, not "characters".

Put all this together and the result is that you're accessing individual *bytes* rather than characters, and in the case of "ö" that results in outputting half of a character/nonsensical bytes.

Use the mb_ functions to iterate and access strings properly by character, not by byte count: [`mb_strlen`](http://php.net/mb_strlen), [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/mb_substr).

Answer (score 0):

[strlen()](http://php.net/strlen) is single-byte:

> `strlen()` returns the number of bytes rather than the number of characters in a string.

UTF-8 is not so you need to use the multi-byte alternative: [mb_strlen()](http://php.net/mb_strlen)

Same rule applies to any almost all string manipulation.